# Как сделать, чтобы по нажатию на каждый элемент вызывалась одна и та же функция, но в функцию попадал именно нажатый элемент?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

Задача: повесить на каждую кнопку с классом "ico-expand" событие, которое возвращает родительский элемент для каждой конкретной кнопки, на которую нажали. В итоге событие висит на каждой кнопке, но на какую бы я не нажал, возвращается родитель именно последней кнопки в структуре. Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему это происходит?

```
const expandButtonsArr = document.body.getElementsByClassName("ico-expand");

for (button of expandButtonsArr) {
    button.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
        const parent = button.parentNode;
        console.log(parent)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Видимо, надо написать так:

```
for (let button of expandButtonsArr)
     ^^^-----
```

Comment: Помогло, спасибо! А в чём механизм проблемы, почему если дописать "let", то работает как надо?

Comment: без неё button - глобальная переменная. let имеет блочный scope и, по-сути, на каждой итерации действует только для неё (итерации),  создается уникальная переменная на каждую итерацию цикла